How to calculate the tool position point based on the tool contact point of a chamfering cutter？
How to calculate the tool position point based on the tool contact point of a chamfering cutter (essentially a frustum with a smaller bottom and larger top) in deburring strategies.The tool axis is fixed.
We know the feed direction at the points on this edge, the normal vector (the sum of the normal vectors of the triangular facets at the point on the edge), and a fixed tool axis direction.
If there is only a tilt angle, the tool position is easy to calculate.
However, if a lead angle is added, there seem to be multiple theoretical solutions for the tool position point. How can we determine the exact point of tangency?
enter image description here
enter image description here
It seems like we are solving three unknowns with two equations, but intuitively, I feel that this problem should have an optimal solution.
Would you like an explanation of the geometric principles involved, or are you looking for a specific algorithm to solve this?

you need to use trigonometry to find the offset distance along the chamfer angle from the contact point, then add that offset to the contact point coordinates to determine the TCP, taking into account the chamfer angle and the cutter geometry

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
